# if(err) throw err; Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I now have

```
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  console.log(candidatePassword)
 console.log(hash)
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, ismatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, ismatch);
  });
}
```

and the logs now are

```
Server is up on port 3000
Connection has been established
Sat Jan 13 2018 14:45:36 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /users/login
Sat Jan 13 2018 14:45:42 GMT+0000 (GMT): POST /users/login
testing1234
undefined
/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/models/user.js:101
    if(err) throw err;
            ^

Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined
    at _async (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:286:46)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:304:13)
    at Function.module.exports.comparePassword (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/models/user.js:100:10)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/routes/users.js:176:12
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4056:16)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
```

It seems here the password is getting shown but not the hash.

**Original**

Hi I'm getting the following error, not sure what's causing it

```
Message sent: <6434a712-dbb6-64f0-4b63-62f206f338c4@bens-mbp.lan>
Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WlVWjq0qIgpSmhJbWloWhUGTHAp3fWC4AAAAbOQTYPu-4HjQWkI0i1uv5Ds
Sat Jan 13 2018 14:24:05 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /users/login
Sat Jan 13 2018 14:24:24 GMT+0000 (GMT): POST /users/login
/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/models/user.js:99
    if(err) throw err;
            ^

Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined
    at _async (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:286:46)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:304:13)
    at Function.module.exports.comparePassword (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/models/user.js:98:10)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/routes/users.js:176:12
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4056:16)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
```

The users are being created I just can't sign in.

Here is the lines causing the error

```
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, ismatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, ismatch);
  });
}
```

here is the passport implementation

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email'
  },
  function(email, password, done) {
    User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown Email Address'});
      }

      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, ismatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(ismatch){
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
      });
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.

Add console.log() for the passed in values shows they are "undefined".

I tested the endpoint out using Postman to add values to the required field(s), solves the problem.

conclusion: the Password is probably empty. Check if it undefined using console.log(). Then pass some value to it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was -

```
E:\web\Projects\webapp\auth.js:15
                if(err) throw err;
                        ^

Error: Illegal arguments: number, string
    at _async (E:\web\Projects\webapp\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:286:46)
    at Object.bcrypt.compare (E:\web\Projects\webapp\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:304:13)
    at Promise (E:\web\Projects\webapp\auth.js:11:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It was because the password was in number and it was throwing an error! I just converted the entered password into string!

Code Before Solving Error-

```
bcrypt.compare(password.toString(), user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    resolve(user);
                }else{
                    //Password Wrong
                    reject("Auth Failed");
                }
            });
```

After Solving Error-
What I did is, I added `.toString()` function in the password argument to convert it into string!

```
bcrypt.compare(password.toString(), user.password, (err, isMatch)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    resolve(user);
                }else{
                    //Password Wrong
                    reject("Auth Failed");
                }
            });
```

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined could mean either your hash value or user input is not recognized a string by the compiler. First try to log your input together with what your user(from database is returning), if your `user.password` does not return a string then you should check your Schema if it was predefined a string and make sure you don't use `select: false` in your password, it may restrict query.

Answer (score 1):

You might have set the select property to false on password. And this is causing the error. The mongoose is not returning the password because you have set the select to false. You now need to explicitly ask for the password when querying.
Use the select method where you are querying for the user and pass the +password as a string like this.

```
.select('+password')
```

Comment: exactly, my case

Answer (score 0):

Try to `console .log()` some values to ensure everything is defined well.

```
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  console.log(candidatePassword)
  console.log(hash)
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, ismatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, ismatch);
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok so `hash` is undefined we now why is not working.

Comment: If you want me to provide any further code let me know, can't seem to get it running

Comment: `user.password` is `undefined` probably when you call `User.comparePassword`.

Comment: Try this in passport:
` User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
   console.log(user.password)`

Comment: I got it, adding the password reset was causing the database hash not to be saved in the database.

Comment: Wright and that's why `user.password` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I dealed with this problem in the past using MariaDB and the culprit was the table column PASSWORD that was in uppercase. When I changed it to lowercase, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem was the header on the insomina, it was passing the password undefined
it was like that
[insomnia before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ltGH.png)
i change to this:
[insomnia after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uccp4.png)

and solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the schema. In my case, I had `select: true`. When I commented it out, it worked fine.

```
password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a password'],
    minlength: 6,
    // select: false
    trim: true,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const comparePassword = async(candidatePassword, hash) => {
  const comparedPassword = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash);

  if (comparedPassword)
    return comparedPassword;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

- I think you are missing the password field in the user or the password is null.
- console.log(user)

The solution which worked for me is:

```
if(!user.password){
 throw new Error('Invalid Credentials')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to use `toObject()`:

```
var pass = user.toObject().userPass;
```